# Trying to exclude certain extensions doing a recursive copy (MSBuild)

Tags: msbuild, createitem

I'm trying to use MSBuild to read in a list of files from a text file, and then perform a recursive copy, copying the contents of those directories files to some staging area, *while excluding certain extensions* (e.g. .tmp files)

I've managed to do most of the above quite easily using CreateItem and the MSBuild copy task, whatever I do the CreateItem task just ignores my Exclude parameter:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RootFolder>c:\temp</RootFolder>
  <ExcludeFilter>*.tmp</ExcludeFilter>
  <StagingDirectory>staging</StagingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <InputFile Include="MyFile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(InputFile)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFolders" TaskParameter="Lines" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <CreateItem Include="$(RootFolder)\%(AllFolders.RelativeDir)**"
              Exclude="$(ExcludeFilter)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AllFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(StagingDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)"
```

Example contents of 'MyFile.txt':

```
somedirectory\
someotherdirectory\
```

(I.e. the paths are relative to `$(RootFolder)` - mention this because I read somewhere that it might be relevant)

I've tried loads of different combinations of Exclude filters, but I never seem to be able to get it to correctly exclude my .tmp files - is there any way of doing this with MSBuild without resorting to xcopy?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to specify the `Exclude` in **absolute path** and change the exclude wildcard to include subdirectory

If you use an absolute path for `Include`, you must use an absolute path for `Exclude`. If you use a relative path for `Include`, you must use a relative path for both.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RootFolder>c:\temp</RootFolder>
  <ExcludeFilter>**\*.tmp</ExcludeFilter>
  <StagingDirectory>staging</StagingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <InputFile Include="MyFile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(InputFile)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFolders" TaskParameter="Lines" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <CreateItem Include="$(RootFolder)\%(AllFolders.RelativeDir)**"
              Exclude="$(RootFolder)\%(AllFolders.RelativeDir)$(ExcludeFilter)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AllFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(StagingDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

### Multiple excludes and absolute path

If you want to exclude multiple items, there is no clean way when you are using absolute path, but you could do with `Remove`.

#### First way : Using Remove and item

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RootFolder>c:\temp</RootFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <InputFile Include="MyFile.txt" />
  <!-- Exclude are defined here -->
  <ExcludeFilters Include="$(RootFolder)\**\*.tmp"/>
  <ExcludeFilters Include="$(RootFolder)\**\*.bmp"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(InputFile)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFolders" TaskParameter="Lines" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <CreateItem Include="$(RootFolder)\%(AllFolders.RelativeDir)**">
    <Output ItemName="AllFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>

  <!-- Removing the wrong extension in item -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <AllFiles Remove="@(ExcludeFilters)"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AllFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(StagingDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

#### Second way : Using Remove and condition

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(InputFile)">
    <Output ItemName="AllFolders" TaskParameter="Lines" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <CreateItem Include="$(RootFolder)\%(AllFolders.RelativeDir)**">
    <Output ItemName="AllFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>

  <!-- Removing the wrong extension in item -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <AllFiles Remove="@(AllFiles)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.tmp'"/>
    <AllFiles Remove="@(AllFiles)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.bmp'"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(AllFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(StagingDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: How about if I want to list multiple exclude filters, for example `**\\*.tmp;**\\*.bmp;`?

Comment: Thanks for posting multiple ways! This remove technique is exactly what the doctor ordered!