# Deploying from MSBuild without overwriting specific files

Tags: msbuild

So here's what I want to do:

I want a build script that will xcopy deploy build outputs for a legacy winform app to a given directory.  I want to specify a list of files to not overwrite (some config files).

I would rather have the list of files to not overwrite be passed as a parameter than hard code them.

This seems to be really unexpectedly hard.  Here's what I have so far:

```
 <!-- A property that is passed a semicolon delimited list of file names -->
 <PropertyGroup>
 <ProtectedFiles/>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <--! An ItemGroup to pick up the files>
 <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToDelete Include=$(DeploymentTargetFolder)\*.* Exclude="@(ProtectedFiles->'$(DeployTargetFolder)\%(identity)')"
 <ItemGroup/>
 <--! the delete isn't working, so I will stop just with that to keep the code brief -->
 <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)"/>
```

The delete just ignores the exclude files and deletes everything

Is there a better way to do this?  It doesn't seem too crazy -- I just want to

- Delete all files from the target directory, except for the config files
- Copy all of the files from the build outputs to the target directory, without overwriting the config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your particular markup appears to confuse [MsBuild $(properties)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) with [MsBuild %(items)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) and [MsBuild @(itemgroups)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/646dk05y.aspx).

ProtectedFiles is a property:

```
 <!-- A property that is passed a semicolon delimited list of file names -->
 <PropertyGroup>
 <ProtectedFiles/>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

But it's being treated as an Item and wouldn't have any %item.metadata:

```
<--! An ItemGroup to pick up the files>
 <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToDelete Include=$(DeploymentTargetFolder)\*.* Exclude="@(ProtectedFiles->'$(DeployTargetFolder)\%(identity)')"
 <ItemGroup/>
```

Save the following markup locally as "foo.xml", then call "**msbuild.exe foo.xml**" and observe the output:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="foo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <FilesProp>FileA.txt;FileB.txt</FilesProp>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProtectedFiles Include="FileA.txt" />
      <ProtectedFiles Include="FileA.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="foo">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="ProtectedFiles ItemGroup: @(ProtectedFiles)" />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="ProtectedFiles ItemGroup transform: @(ProtectedFiles->'%(Identity)')" />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="FilesProp Property: $(FilesProp)" />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="FilesProp Property: @(FilesProp->'%(FilesProp.Identity)')" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Will yield the following output:

```
foo:
  ProtectedFiles ItemGroup: FileA.txt;FileA.txt
  ProtectedFiles ItemGroup transform: FileA.txt;FileA.txt
  FilesProp Property: FileA.txt;FileB.txt
  FilesProp Property:
```

If you're unable to change the design and need to convert a Property comprising a semi-colon delimited list of file paths, use the [MsBuild <CreateItem /> task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx).

Add this markup to foo.xml occurring after the Foo target, then invoke msbuild again, but using the "bar" target (e.g. **msbuild.exe foo.xml /t:bar**)

```
<Target Name="bar">

    <CreateItem Include="$(FilesProp)">
       <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TheFiles"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <Message Text="TheFiles ItemGroup: @(TheFiles)" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="Output each item: %(TheFiles.Identity)" Importance="high" />

</Target>
```

Will yield the following output:

```
bar:
  TheFiles ItemGroup: FileA.txt;FileB.txt
  Output each item: FileA.txt
  Output each item: FileB.txt
```

Next you should rethink some of your assumptions.  I don't believe the file extension should be the determining factor when deciding which files to update, rather you should rely on MsBuild's ability to build tasks incrementally allowing it to perform a task only if the inputs are newer than the outputs.  You can do this by using an [MsBuild <Copy /> task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) configured to skip unchanged files.

Add this markup to the above Xml file, then modify the $(SourceFolder) and $(TargetFolder) to point to a source folder you'd like to copy recursively, and a destination folder to place the files.  Build using "**msbuild.exe foo.xml /t:Deployment**" and observe the output.

```
<Target Name="Deployment">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceFolder>c:\sourcefolder\</SourceFolder>
        <TargetFolder>c:\destinationfolder\</TargetFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <CreateItem Include="$(SourceFolder)\**\*.*">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToCopy" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetFolder)%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />

</Target>
```

Without modifying any of the source files, run the command again and note that no files were copied.

Modify a file in the source folder, then run the command again.  Notice that only the updated files were copied?

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Nick:  Thank you, this looks extremely promising.  I did know about the  "skip unchanged" option, however, for this set of files I want to protect, I don't want to copy them even if the source is newer.  The files that I am looking to protect contain settings that are specific to testing.  They ensure that our testers connect to the Q/A database, and never production, and if there are web services being called, to use test URLs and not production endpoints. I think my best option might be to use transforms on the the config files, but ironically, I thought this would be easier

Comment: Why not include the logic specifying the test environment as part of the deployment task?  You can do a find-replace within a file, create a custom task to step through an XML file replacing values, or anything else so you don't have to modify two versions of the file, or have a process that requires manual intervention should the structure of the config files change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an already existing post, similar to this. Please check this [Trying to exclude certain extensions doing a recursive copy (MSBuild)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031021/trying-to-exclude-certain-extensions-doing-a-recursive-copy-msbuild)